# switch output file redirection in the middle of a bash script

Tags: bash, file-descriptor, tee

I just want to save the output of my script at a place I don't know at the beginning of the script. I try something but I'm pretty sure that it's ugly.
Is there an elegant way to do that:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Here I don't know where to write outputfile so I create a tmpfile
fic=$(mktemp -t)
trap 'rm -f $fic' EXIT
rm -f $fic
:> $fic
exec 3<> $fic
exec 1>&3
exec 2>&3

# some code in particular reading options and dest dir
echo foo
dir="."

# Here I finally know where I can write my output
fic2=$dir/log.log

cp -f $fic $fic2
exec 3>&- # close fd #3
exec 1>> $fic2
exec 2>&1

echo bar
```

Furthermore, I would like to tee the entire output, something like $ exec ... >(tee $fic)$ but I failed to find a solution.

Thanks a lot for any advice.
PJLM

Comment: `exec > >(tee "$fic") 2>&1`?

Comment: Of course, in a simple way, what you propose @melpomene works fine. But I want to change the redirection in the middle of the script. So your solution is ok for the first part, but not the second one, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that **both output files are on the same file system**, you can just `mv` the output file.  The file descriptors you have open will continue to work.

```
exec 1>/tmp/out1 2>&1
echo out1
mv /tmp/out1 /tmp/out2   # replace with your desired destination
echo out2
```

---

If you want to `tee` the output, and, again, both output files are on the same filesystem, you can do pretty much the same thing (once `tee` has opened the file for writing it will likewise keep writing to the same fd even if the file moves).

```
log1=$(mktemp)
exec 3>"$log1"
exec 1> >(tee /dev/fd/3) 2>&1
echo out1
mv "$log1" "$log2"
echo out2
```

<sup>Note that instead of doing `>(tee "$log1")` I first open fd 3 in the shell and then use `>(tee /dev/fd/3)`.  This is because otherwise there is a potential race condition where `tee` will not have opened the file by the time we get to the `mv` step.  (`exec` only waits until the *subshell* in which `tee` will run has started, but it takes some time for `tee` itself to start and open the file).</sup>

---

If your first and second **output files may not be on the same file system**, you will have to do some more advanced shuffling and make sure that writing to the first file finishes before copying it.

In the case of a simple redirect, we need to close the file descriptors before moving:

```
exec 1>"$log1" 2>&1
echo out1
exec 1>&- 2>&-
mv "$log1" "$log2"
exec 1>>"$log2" 2>&1
echo out2
```

---

In the case of a process substitution with output files potentially on different file systems, we need to make sure that the process substitution finishes before moving the file:

```
exec 3>&1 4>&2                # save original stdout, stderr
exec 1> >(tee "$log1") 2>&1   # redirect to tee
pid=$!                        # save pid of tee's subshell

echo out1
exec 1>&3 2>&4                # restore original stdout, stderr

# wait until tee is done. on newer bash can use `wait $pid` instead
while kill -0 $pid 2>/dev/null; do :; done

mv "$log1" "$log2"

# repeat steps above for new file
exec 3>&1 4>&2
exec 1> >(tee -a "$log2") 2>&1
pid=$!
echo out2
exec 1>&3 2>&4
while kill -0 $pid 2>/dev/null; do :; done
```

Comment: Ok, very helpful and it simplifies a lot my script.
Now I just want to add some `tee` in it, to have also on standard output.

Comment: Edited the answer to add the `tee` variant.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The last comment is the good solution for me. And very instructive.

Comment: Will continue to work **if** both locations are on the same filesystem. If they're on different partitions, then your old handle will be writing to an unlinked copy.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I covered that in the 3rd section of the answer but I'll add something up top for clarity